# Convertir JSON string en Objecto o List<string> C#

Tags: c#, json

Estoy recuperando un `json` de Geolocalizacion, el cual seria este:

```
{
  "query": "24.48.0.1",
  "status": "success",
  "country": "Canada",
  "countryCode": "CA",
  "region": "QC",
  "regionName": "Quebec",
  "city": "Montreal",
  "zip": "H1S",
  "lat": 45.5808,
  "lon": -73.5825,
  "timezone": "America/Toronto",
  "isp": "Le Groupe Videotron Ltee",
  "org": "Videotron Ltee",
  "as": "AS5769 Videotron Telecom Ltee"
}
```

Estoy usando esto (el que me trae el `json` anterior es el `GetData`):

```
public string IpPublic()
        {
            return new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com").Trim();
        }

        public string GetData(string ip)
        {
            string datos = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://ip-api.com/json/"+ip);
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datos);
        }
```

Arme un modelo para mapearlo, el cual es este:

```
namespace P3W_FrontEnd.Models
{
    public class IPAPI
    {
        public string query { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string countryCode { get; set; }
        public string region { get; set; }
        public string regionName { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string zip { get; set; }
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lon { get; set; }
        public string timezone { get; set; }
        public string isp { get; set; }
        public string org { get; set; }
        public string @as { get; set; }

        
    }

    public class IPAPIObject
    {
        public List<IPAPI> ListaIP { get; set; }
    }

}
```

al hacer esto en el controlador, no me funciona

```
string ip = ipX.IpPublic();
string data = ipX.GetData(ip);
var jsonIp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IPAPIObject>>(data);
```

La cuestion es que recupero y mando al controlador el `string`, pero no logro mapearlos con el fin de solo recuperar en ese `string` o lista el pais y la ciudad, como haria eso?

Comment: En ningun momento veo que le digas a que tipo de objeto lo queres convertir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te esta faltando deserealizar el string a tu objeto. Tu json no es un array entonces si lo queres convertir a un array te va a romper seguro, y te coloque tu objeto para retornar en el metodo, sino estarias deserealizando para enviarlo como string de nuevo.

```
public async IPAPI GetData(string ip)
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  
  var datos = await client.GetAsync("http://ip-api.com/json/"+ip);
  
  return JsonConvert.Desearealize<IPAPI>(await datos.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

Ejemplo: si llamas al metodo desde otro metodo:

```
public void LlamarApi()
{
   var resultado = GetData("Ip");
   resultado.country; // podes acceder a todas las propiedades, lo parseaste en el metodo anterior.
}
```

Comment: Gracias, perdona como hago para acceder a los datos del objeto?

Comment: En tu ejemplo de json no veo que sea una lista sino un unico objeto.